# How to set value of autocomplete deluxe via AJAX?

Tags: 8

I am using https://www.drupal.org/project/autocomplete_deluxe in Drupal 8.

```
function custom_module_form_node_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {  
  $form['field_all_value']['widget']['value']['#ajax'] = [
    'event' => 'change',
    'callback' => 'get_ajax_callback',
    'wrapper' => 'edit-field-test-wrapper'
  ];
}

function get_ajax_callback(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  $form['field_test']['widget']['target_id']['#default_value'] = 'A, B';

  return $form['field_test'];
}
```

On checkbox check I have to fill all the values in auto deluxe form field.

Comment: Did you try with `$form['field_test']['widget']['target_id']['#default_value'] = ['A', 'B'];` ?

Comment: Hi @berramou tried not working

Comment: Hey,  you can fill an input and dump it in submit to see how auto deluxe module fill the input an then do the  same .